# Typescript: why keyof Union is never

Tags: typescript

This is my **Typescript** code:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  content: string
}

type Union = Omit<Todo, 'content'> | {
  name: string
};
type key = keyof Union; // never
```

My question is that why the type key is never?

Comment: however, use interface and extends works well

Comment: your union is equivalent to `{ title: string } | { name: string }` NOT to `{ title: string; name: string }`

Answer (score 4):

Because `extends` works like intersection `&`.

```js
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  content: string
}

// a bit simplified
type A =  Omit<Todo, 'content'> // { title: string }
type B = { name: string };

type Union = A | B

type key = keyof Union; // never
```

`keyof` operator checks if union type has any sharable property. In your case neither `A` nor `B` has not same property.

Take a look on next example:

```js
type A = { name: string, age: number }
type B = { name: string };

type Union = A | B

type key = keyof Union; // name
```

Here, keyof will return "name". because this property exists in both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `|` operator. If you substitute it with `&`, you will get the result you expect:

```js
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  content: string
}

type Union = Omit<Todo, 'content'> & {
  name: string
};
type key = keyof Union; // "title" | "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of types as [Sets](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/venn-diagrams.html) of values.

Any value can be type. It is an infinite set of values.

What `keyof` operator does is extract the keys of a Set and make them as types:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
}

type K = keyof Todo; // "title"

// The Set K has only "title" as valid value
```

When you bring in another type (another set of values) like `Person`

```
type Person = {
  name: string
};

type P = keyof Person; // "name"

// The Set P has only "name" as valid value
```

and find a union of `keys` of Set `Todo` and Set `Person`, this is what happens:

```
type key = keyof (Todo | Person); 
// it tries to find any common value between keys of Todo and Person i.e. "title", "name". 
// Since these are two distinct sets, there is no value in common. 
// TypeScript represents an empty Set as `never`.
```

This the reason you get `never`:

```
keyof (A | B) = (keyof A) & (keyof B)
```